# Apache .htaccess: How to rewrite backslash with slash on Firefox?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**How to rewrite backslash`'\'`with slash`'/'`on Firefox?**

Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera has build browser rewrite backslash with slash.
But Firefox 3.6.13 returns *404 error page*.

```
# Why Firefox returns 404 error page?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\\(.*)
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Apache and FF bug, https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35256
Hopefully it'll be fixed in soon feature.

> 1. AllowEncodedSlashes should really be "on" by default and probably even deprecated. ...
> 2. Nowhere the RFCs is a backslash `(\)` listed as a reserved character. Therefore a `%5C`
>      **should** always be decoded the same as `%7E` is converted to a tilde `(~)`.

To solve it on Apache: 
add `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in `VirtualHost` httpd-vhosts.conf or httpd.conf, and .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\\(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, that seems to be correct behavior. Backslashes are not amongst the characters allowed in a HTTP or HTTPS URL (as per [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)), therefore they should be escaped. Note that the RFC **explicitly** mentions backslash as an unsafe character:

> Other characters are unsafe because
>      gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
>      such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",
>      "[", "]", and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

In other words, Firefox is doing the correct thing, even if it breaks pages which are incorrectly using backslashes (mostly from confusing URL syntax with Windows path syntax). Other browsers are trying to read the page author's mind, and they convert the backslashes to forward slashes before sending the request; whether this is a Good Thing is a matter of opinion.

Did you try to match on the escaped version of the backslash - `%5C` ?

Comment: As for the opinion - I think trying to *guess* the author's intent is doomed to failure (see the `quirks mode` minefield in the last decade, created by such attempts at mind reading). If the URL is badly broken, the browser shouldn't try to "fix" it - it should break instead of reinforcing the author's habit of writing bad code. Fixing it *for* the author leads to "eh, works for me".

Comment: Thanks for replay! But `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)%5c(.*)$` does not solve it either. Just Firefox for www.google.com/intl/en\about.html will return 404 error page, other browsers'll return www.google.com/intl/en/about.htm

Comment: @Binyamin: Yes, and it always will, because FF is actually sending the backslash, whereas others will replace it with a slash; the rewrite should happen at your server (not at Google's), it won't fix this behavior on *all* servers. Also, do you have the `[NC]` argument (case insensitive matching)?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with `NC` either. Some other advice how to rewrite backslash with slash on FF!?