# Rewrite all requests to index.php not working when \ in URl

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine on     
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/ [R=301,L]    
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

It rewrite almost all request to index.php, but when I put backslash (\) in URL, just like 
mysite.com/sth\ then it shows apache 404 error. How to fix it? Browsers other than firefox replaces \ to / but I want it to work in fx too.
I switched AllowEncodedSlashes to On but even after apache restart it still doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache .htaccess: How to rewrite backslash with slash on Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887928/apache-htaccess-how-to-rewrite-backslash-with-slash-on-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and make sure you enable allow override all in httpd.conf and mod_rewrite library is enabled in same httpd.conf file.If it works flag it as answered and thumbs-up.